# Spark Sql query fails

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, cassandra-2.0

Using Sparks 2/java/Cassanda2.2
Trying to run a simple sparks sql query, it errors:
Tried as below, + variations like "'LAX'", and '=' instead of '=='.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`LAX`' given input columns: [transdate, origin]; line 1 pos 42;
'Project ['origin]
+- 'Filter (origin#1 = 'LAX)
   +- SubqueryAlias origins
      +- LogicalRDD [transdate#0, origin#1]

JavaRDD<TransByDate> originDateRDD = javaFunctions(sc).cassandraTable("trans", "trans_by_date", CassandraJavaUtil.mapRowTo(TransByDate.class)).select(CassandraJavaUtil.column("origin"), CassandraJavaUtil.column("trans_date").as("transdate"));

long cnt1= originDateRDD.count();
System.out.println("sqlLike originDateRDD.count: "+cnt1); --> 406000
Dataset<Row> originDF = sparks.createDataFrame(originDateRDD, TransByDate.class);
originDF.createOrReplaceTempView("origins");
Dataset<Row> originlike = sparks.sql("SELECT origin FROM origins WHERE origin =="+ "LAX");
```

I have enabled Hive Support (if that helps)
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the column value inside single quote. Your query should look like below.

```
Dataset<Row> originlike = spark.sql("SELECT origin FROM origins WHERE origin == "+"'LAX'");
```

You can refer [Querying Cassandra data using Spark SQL in Java](https://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/5.0/datastax_enterprise/spark/sparkSqlJava.html) for more detail.

Like query should be like below.

```
Dataset<Row> originlike = spark.sql("SELECT origin FROM origins WHERE origin like 'LA%'");
```

Comment: Yes this works == "+"'LAX'". I thought I had tried this combination - but with some other errors - who knows. Still **LIKE "+a+"%"** (a = L) still does not that work- gives the same exception: `mismatched input 'FROM' expecting {<EOF>, 'WHERE', 'GROUP', 'ORDER', 'HAVING', 'LIMIT', 'LATERAL', 'WINDOW', 'UNION', 'EXCEPT', 'INTERSECT', 'SORT', 'CLUSTER', 'DISTRIBUTE'}(line 1, pos 14)

== SQL ==
SELECT origin FROM origins WHERE origin LIKE L%`

Comment: Was having an issue in a HAVING clause and wrapping the contents of HAVING in single quotes did the trick. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Hive is not the problem, here is the line that is your problem:

`` Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`LAX`' given input columns: [transdate, origin]; line 1 pos 42; ``

What this is saying is that among the column names, none are named LAX. The scala DSL asks for `===` when matching a value that is a key within a column, perahps something similar would be more ideal, something like a `origins.filter($"origin === "LAX")`

Comment: I am using java, now when I try : `"SELECT origin FROM origins WHERE origin === "+"LAX" `   Exception in thread "main"     `org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException: 
mismatched input 'FROM' expecting {<EOF>, 'WHERE', 'GROUP', 'ORDER', 'HAVING', 'LIMIT', 'LATERAL', 'WINDOW', 'UNION', 'EXCEPT', 'INTERSECT', 'SORT', 'CLUSTER', 'DISTRIBUTE'}(line 1, pos 14)

== SQL ==
SELECT origin FROM origins WHERE origin === LAX `      I just have 2 columns in my DF origin and transdate.  I get identical error when I try query `"LIKE L%" `(that us what I actually need to get to)

Comment: Column names are correct in the Df - I can print and see them. But Df.show() - throws all kinds of exceptions.

Comment: The issue still exists whatever I try:  `==  or === , "LAX"  "'LAX'"`, or same with using `LIKE L%`

Comment: I finally figured this Like out :  `LIKE '"+a+"%'" ` . So the % itself also needs to be in quote ( ' ') :  `LIKE 'L%'`