# Spark Sql mapping issue

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Sparks2/Java8 Cassandra2
Trying to read some data from Cassandra and then run a group by query in sparks.  I have only 2 columns in my DF
transdate (Date), origin (String)

```
Dataset<Row> maxOrigindate = sparks.sql("SELECT origin, transdate, COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM origins  GROUP BY (origin,transdate) ORDER BY cnt DESC LIMIT 1"); `
```

Get Error:

```
 `Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: expression 'origins.`origin`' is neither present in the group by, nor is it an aggregate function. Add to group by or wrap in first() (or first_value)`
```

The group by issue got solved removing  ( ) in group by as below

Complete code: (trying to get max number of trans on date for a origin/location)

```
JavaRDD<TransByDate> originDateRDD = javaFunctions(sc).cassandraTable("trans", "trans_by_date", CassandraJavaUtil.mapRowTo(TransByDate.class))
                    .select(CassandraJavaUtil.column("origin"), CassandraJavaUtil.column("trans_date").as("transdate")).limit((long)100) ;
Dataset<Row> originDF = sparks.createDataFrame(originDateRDD, TransByDate.class);
String[] columns = originDF.columns();
System.out.println("originDF columns: "+columns[0]+" "+columns[1]) ; -> transdate origin
originDF.createOrReplaceTempView("origins");

Dataset<Row> maxOrigindate = sparks.sql("SELECT origin, transdate, COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM origins  GROUP BY origin,transdate ORDER BY cnt DESC LIMIT 1"); 
List list = maxOrigindate.collectAsList(); -> Exception here
int j = list.size();
```

originDF **columns**: transdate origin

```
`public static class TransByDate implements Serializable {
        private String origin;
        private Date transdate;

        public TransByDate() { }

        public TransByDate (String origin, Date transdate) { 
            this.origin = origin;
            this.transdate= transdate;

        }

        public String getOrigin() { return origin; }
        public void setOrigin(String origin) { this.origin = origin; }

        public Date getTransdate() { return transdate; }
        public void setTransdate(Date transdate) { this.transdate = transdate; }

    }
```

**Schema**

```
root
 |-- transdate: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- date: integer (nullable = false)
 |    |-- day: integer (nullable = false)
 |    |-- hours: integer (nullable = false)
 |    |-- minutes: integer (nullable = false)
 |    |-- month: integer (nullable = false)
 |    |-- seconds: integer (nullable = false)
 |    |-- time: long (nullable = false)
 |    |-- timezoneOffset: integer (nullable = false)
 |    |-- year: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- origin: string (nullable = true)
```

**Exception**
ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 12)
scala.MatchError: Sun Jan 01 00:00:00 PST 2012 (of class java.util.Date)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$StructConverter.toCatalystImpl(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:256)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$StructConverter.toCatalystImpl(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:251)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$CatalystTypeConverter.toCatalyst(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:103)
 ....
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 2.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 12, localhost): scala.MatchError: Sun Jan 01 00:00:00 PST 2012 (of class java.util.Date)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$StructConverter.toCatalystImpl(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:256)
...
Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1454)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1442)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1441)
...
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$collectAsList$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2184)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withCallback(Dataset.scala:2559)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.collectAsList(Dataset.scala:2184)
    **at spark.SparkTest.sqlMaxCount(SparkTest.java:244)  -> List list = maxOrigindate.collectAsList();**

Caused by: **scala.MatchError**: Sun Jan 01 00:00:00 PST 2012 (of **class java.util.Date**)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$StructConverter.toCatalystImpl(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:256)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$StructConverter.toCatalystImpl(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:251)

Comment: Just remove the bracket from the group by expression i.e. group by origin, transdate

Comment: @Rajat - thx, went past that error, but very next line `List list = maxOrigindate.collectAsList(); ` whole bunch of exceptions: `scala.MatchError: Sun Jan 01 00:00:00 PST 2012 (of class java.util.Date)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$StructConverter.toCatalystImpl(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:256)  .....`  I thought HellowWorld was supposed to be easy but

Comment: Added code details, the query line is not giving exception now, but next line collectAsList()

Comment: So any operation on the DF (count, collect) is giving an exception: **Caused by: scala.MatchError: Sun Jan 01 00:00:00 PST 2012 (of class java.util.Date)** . But on DF I can do: columns, printSchema, createOrReplaceTempView.

Comment: As Saprk is lazyily evaulated , when you are doing count or collect, action is being called and at time your dataframe is actually being created. There must a datatype mismatch between your schema and data present.

Comment: From the error it does sound like a data type mismatch. But that should not be the case. The datatype in the underlying DB (Cassandra) is datetime. Data has been loaded into the DB using java Date. The class TransByDate has the var transdate set as Date.I can print the RDD the date prints fine: Sun Jan 01 00:00:00 PST 2012.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132527/discussion-between-rajat-mishra-and-sam-t).

Comment: Anyone has any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting below error.

```
Caused by: scala.MatchError: Sun Jan 01 00:00:00 PST 2012 (of class java.util.Date) at
```

This error is because Spark sql supports `java.sql.Date` type. Please check the Spark documentation [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#data-types). You can also refer [SPARK-2562](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-2562).

Comment: Yes this works. **Changed the datatype in the class to java.sql.Date**

Comment: Only issue still open in the long saga is a sql [basic problem] [1]   [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41473949/spark-sql-query-fails/41474803#41474803

Answer (score 1):

change the query to

```
Dataset<Row> maxOrigindate = sparks.sql("SELECT origin, 
transdate, 
COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM origins  GROUP BY origin,transdate 
ORDER BY cnt DESC LIMIT 1");
```

this will work.